# How to add in a HTML video that loops and plays automaticly

Tags: html, video

Ive been trying everything I know but I cant seem to just add in the video, in the center of the page, to loop non-stop. Am I using a wrong code or...?

I am currently using the latest Firefox browser

Code: http://pastebin.com/NJywJwaW

Answer (score 0):

Try now

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.autoplay = true;
    vid.loop = true;
    vid.controls = false;
    vid.load();
 </script>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#000000">
 <center>
 <video id="myVideo" autoplay>
 <source src="sk1logo1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do I have to make a javascript file that links with the HTML file?

Comment: And will the video have controls? If it does, how do I take out the controls or any borders with it?

Comment: I dont know why its still not working, my MP4 file is in the same folder as this and I did all you said to..

Comment: hmm... will look into it. I can see in my markup the video tag is not closed. will update. don't know if that was the problem but try with the updated markup @OwenCraddock